# Use Wallabag instance running on Oracle cloud from anywhere

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to run the Wallabag instance on the Free-Oracle-Cloud tier.

Oracle cloud VM gave me an IP-Address: A.B.C.D

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: wallabag/wallabag
    container_name: wallabag
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test:
       [
          "CMD",
          "wget",
          "--no-verbose",
          "--tries=1",
          "--spider",
          "http://localhost",
       ]
      interval: 1m
      timeout: 3s
  environment:
      - SYMFONY__ENV__DOMAIN_NAME=http://127.0.0.1:8012
      - SYMFONY__ENV__SERVER_NAME="My Wallabag Instance"
  ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8012:80
  volumes:
      - ./data:/var/www/wallabag/data
      - ./images:/var/www/wallabag/web/assets/images
```

After that I ran: `docker-compose up -d`

To check the status: `docker ps -a | grep wallabag`

Output: `4fcadf00db88   wallabag/wallabag   "/entrypoint.sh wall…"   9 seconds ago   Restarting (1) 1 second ago             wallabag`

But the thing is I cannot access Wallabag service from the internet. I tried replacing `127.0.0.1` to my IPAddress `A.B.C.D`

Error:

> ERROR: for wallabag  Cannot start service app: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint wallabag (557e62f6b481d821cd3228a98deaa9cf4e723f0c8ee1ce621bf13): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 A.B.C.D:8012: bind: cannot assign requested address

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  environment:
      - SYMFONY__ENV__DOMAIN_NAME=http://A.B.C.D:8012
      - SYMFONY__ENV__SERVER_NAME="My Wallabag Instance"
  ports:
      - 8012:80
```

this should work

Comment: Thank you @Def Soudani.
It worked like a charm!